# How do back office systems calculate warrant average net price?

Tags: warrant, settlement

I encountered an interesting formula a vendor gave me for how they calculate Average Net Price:

Average Px = Weighted Average Price
Average Px (Net) = (abs(warrant principal) + signed Fees and Commissions + Accrued) / filled quantity
Warrant Principal = Market Value = filled qty * (`PRICING_MULTIPLIER` / `WRT_SH_PER`) * Average Price

where `PRICING_MULTIPLIER` and `WRT_SH_PER` are Bloomberg fields.

This formula doesn't make a ton of sense to me, because:

1. `PRICING_MULTIPLIER` is relative to a pricing source/quoted price
2. `WRT_SH_PER` is simply the conversion ratio to common stock the warrant unit holder would get upon exercise (so not clear why it would be involved in calculating Avg Px Net).
3. In Bloomberg, these values are always identical.  e.g., even when the `WRT_SH_PER` is not 1, it's value is equal to the `PRICING_MULTIPLIER`, and so the sub-formula (`PRICING_MULTIPLIER` / `WRT_SH_PER`) simplifies to just `1`.

What am I missing here?  Is the vendor just doing silly things?  In general, the risk here would be that the price would be incorrect due to erroneous/over-complicated formula. But maybe there is some markets where this formula actually makes sense for reasons I am unaware?